# How to fix spikes and missing values in times series?

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation

I have some data representing times series about houses costs in specific areas. Some of the values along the times series (30 points = 30 months) are missing or are totally wrong (huge spikes).

What I am doing right now is to calculate the average and the standard deviation to eliminate first zeros and spikes and replace them with a smooth interpolation from the extremes of the holes. It works fine in some cases but not always.

Is there any better way to fix these problems?

**UPDATED**

An idea may be the "1-D median filtering" (Media filter)

Answer (score 1):

As you well mention, my first approach would be using a [1-D median filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter). Such filter goes through each sample of the signal, centers a window of length $N$ (typically an odd number) in it, and replaces its value by the median of the window itself. It is particularly good to remove abnormally large spikes in your signal and/or missing values.

Depending on your platform, the implementation will differ. I use MATLAB a lot and it has already its own built-in function [`medfilt1`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html). You will find in its documentation a very nice example (I tried to include it, but I cannot post so many links in an answer yet).

Answer (score -1):

Some ideas:

You could try with filters like moving average, savitsky-golay, etc.
Or Interquantilerange(IQR) to remove outliers